# Combinations in R

Tags: r, combinations

Hi so I am trying to do validation of my Basket for Association rules and I want to create combinations of my data frame into the same column.

So for example from this DF of UserId and Basket,

```
> head(validDF)
  UserID                    Basket
1    935          Toy Story (1995)
2    935   Dead Man Walking (1995)
3    935 Mr. Holland's Opus (1995)
4    936              Fargo (1996)
5    936           Rock The (1996)
6    936            Twister (1996)
```

I want to create these combinations:

```
  UserID                    Basket
1    935          Toy Story (1995), Dead Man Walking (1995)
2    935   Dead Man Walking (1995), Toy Story (1995)
3    935 Mr. Holland's Opus (1995), Toy Story (1995)
4    935 Mr. Holland's Opus (1995), Dead Man Walking (1995)
5    936              Fargo (1996), Rock The (1996)
6    936           Rock The (1996), Fargo (1996)
7    936            Twister (1996), Fargo (1996)
8    936            Twister (1996), Rock The (1996)
```

Anyone has any idea how to do it?

to use R to generate these combination based on UserId in the dataset, R isn't my strongest language. So any help is appreciated!

Comment: those aren't permutations, they're combinations (unless Dead Man Walking/Toy Story is different in your mind from Toy Story/Dead Man Walking). See `?combn` or search it on SO

Comment: Is it necessary to add the combinations to the basket variable? The combinations you listed are just random or is there a specific rule behind it? For me it looks like random sampling with replacement from the user ID pool. `group_by()`and `sample_n()`or `sample_frac()`might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 # data frame
    validDF = data.frame(
    UserID = c(935, 935, 935, 936, 936, 936),                
    Basket = c("Toy Story (1995)", "Dead Man Walking (1995)", "Mr. Holland's Opus (1995)",
               "Fargo (1996)", "Rock The (1996)", "Twister (1996)"))

    res = lapply(unique(validDF$UserID), function(x){
      ls_Basket <- as.character(validDF$Basket[validDF$UserID == x])
      res_int = permutations(n = 3, r=2, v= ls_Basket)
      data.frame(UserID = x, Basket = apply(res_int, 1, paste, collapse = ", "))
    })
    res <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

But in your example, you mix permutation (3 movies=> 6 permutations) and combination (3 movies => 3 combinations)